# Why does the maximal irrelevant is out of this correspondence?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm solving the Hartshorne's questions and I didn't understand why $S_+$ doesn't occur in this equivalence:

[image]

**My reasoning**

By the previous exercise, if $X$ is an algebraic set in $\mathbb P^n$, we have $Z(I(X))=\overline X= X$.

If $\mathfrak a$ is a radical homogeneous ideal, by the homogeneous Hilbert Nullstellensatz, we have $I(Z(\mathfrak a))=\sqrt {\mathfrak a}=\mathfrak a$ (since ${\mathfrak a}$ is ideal).

So, it seems that $S_+$ occurs in this equivalence, where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for intuition, if you think about projective varieties in terms of their cone in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$, then $S_+$ corresponds to the origin, which we exclude as a point of projective space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Fact*. If $\mathfrak a\subset S=k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ is a homogeneous ideal, then $Z(\mathfrak a)=\emptyset$ if and only if $\sqrt{\mathfrak a}=S$ or $\sqrt{\mathfrak a}=S_+$.

So in the correspondence between algebraic sets in $\mathbb P_k^n$ and homogeneous radical ideals in $S$ (the usual $\mathfrak a\mapsto Z(\mathfrak a)$ with inverse $X\mapsto I(X)$), $S_+=(x_0,\dots,x_n)$ does not appear, because we already have $\mathfrak a=S$ corresponding $\emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. have a nice day.